# How can I find the path of a file in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

From what I know you can find the path of a file in the internal storage with java simply by using:

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();    
File file = new File(path + "/filename");
```

But how do I do this using kotlin?

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin, when you see a getter method from a Java class, you can omit the `get`, change the first letter to lower-case, and use it like a Kotlin property:

```
val path = context.filesDir.absolutePath
val file = File("$path/filename")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is now a Kotlin library function for this.  This should be the better choice as your code will be able to be used on multiple platforms:

```
import kotlin.io.path.Path
import kotlin.io.path.absolutePathString

val fullPath = Path(relativeName).absolutePathString()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/absolute-path-string.html